# Concordances with Python

Tags: python

Your goals are to prompt the user for a text file to analyze. You will also be provided 
with a file of stop words—words that will be ignored when you analyze the file. After 
creating the concordance,  print the concordance results as indicated in the example 
output below. For each word in the concordance you will print:

- the word
- the total number of occurrences
- for each occurrence:

  - the line number in the file (the first line is line #1)
  - the local context. The local context is the original line with the specified word in all upper case.

This is what I have so far:

```
import string
file_str = raw_input("What file to analyze:")
file_obj = open(file_str)
for line in file_obj.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    split_line = line.split()
    for word in split_line:
        word = word.lower()
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
```

I'm not sure where to go from there!

Comment: There were similar question on SO in the last couple of days.  You might want to browse the archive a bit.

Comment: you have a syntax issue: indent all the code below the fourth line. How do you define concordances?

Comment: What part are you trying to do that you're stuck on?

Comment: I would start by analyzing what data structures you need. How will you store the words? How will you store the information you need about each word? Then figure out how you will gather that information.

Comment: @Sven there are other questions on the same homework, but they may spoil elements of answer to the OP. If anything Emily should try to formulate the problem in a more precise way. Consider this as SO's special bonus exercise for her :-)

Comment: we we're given txt files with storys such as itsy bitsy spider and we had to count the main word in it and then capitalize it Example Output: Analyze what file: itsy_bitsy_spider.txt Concordance for file itsy_bitsy_spider.txt itsy : Total Count: 2 Line:1: The ITSY Bitsy spider crawled up the water spout Line:4: and the ITSY Bitsy spider went up the spout again! crawled : Total Count: 1 Line:1: The Itsy Bitsy spider CRAWLED up the water spout spout : Total Count: 2 Line:1: The Itsy Bitsy spider crawled up the water SPOUT Line:4: and the Itsy Bitsy spider went up the SPOUT again!

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you need is a counter you increment on each iteration of the outer loop, because you are asked to provide some information about line numbers.

Then the next step is to have a dictionary. Outside the loop

```
words = {}
```

Each time you encounter a word, check if it is already a key in the dictionary.

```
if word in words:
```

If so, update the entry

```
    word_info = words[word]
    word_info = // something changed
    // possibly you need this depending on the type of word_info
    words[word] = word_info
```

If not, create a new entry

```
else:
    word_info = // something
    words[word] = word_info
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out what kind of value word_info should be.

Comment: we we're given txt files with storys such as itsy bitsy spider

and we had to count the main word in it and then capitalize it

Example Output:
Analyze what file: itsy_bitsy_spider.txt
Concordance for file itsy_bitsy_spider.txt
itsy : Total Count: 2
Line:1: The ITSY Bitsy spider crawled up the water spout
Line:4: and the ITSY Bitsy spider went up the spout again!
crawled : Total Count: 1
Line:1: The Itsy Bitsy spider CRAWLED up the water spout
spout : Total Count: 2
Line:1: The Itsy Bitsy spider crawled up the water SPOUT
Line:4: and the Itsy Bitsy spider went up the SPOUT again!